# What causes overfitting in the algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


#reproducible random seed
seed = 1
np.random.seed(seed)

#Import and normalize the data
df = pd.read_csv('creditcard.csv')


#Exploring the data

# print df.head()
# print df.describe()
# print df.isnull().sum()


# count_class = pd.value_counts(df['Class'])
# count_class.plot(kind = 'bar')
# plt.title('Fraud class histogram')
# plt.xlabel('class')
# plt.ylabel('Frequency')
# plt.show()

# print('Clearly the data is totally unbalanced!')

#to normalize the amount column
# data['normAmount'] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data['Amount'].reshape(-1, 1))
df['normAmount'] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df['Amount'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
df = df.drop(['Time','V28','V27','V26','V25','V24','V23','V22','V20','V15','V13','V8','Amount'], axis =1)
X = df.iloc[:,df.columns!='Class']
Y = df.iloc[:,df.columns=='Class']

# number of records in the minority class
number_record_fraud = len(df[df.Class==1])
fraud_indices = np.array(df[df.Class==1].index)

#picking normal class
normal_indices = np.array(df[df.Class==0].index)

#select random x(number_record_fraud) numbers from normal_indices
random_normal_indices = np.random.choice(normal_indices,number_record_fraud,replace=False)
random_normal_indices = np.array(random_normal_indices)

#under sample data
under_sample_indices = np.concatenate([fraud_indices,random_normal_indices])
under_sample_data = df.iloc[under_sample_indices,:]

X_undersample = under_sample_data.iloc[:,under_sample_data.columns!='Class']
Y_undersample = under_sample_data.iloc[:,under_sample_data.columns=='Class']

# split data into train and test dataset
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.3)
X_train_undersample,X_test_undersample,Y_train_undersample,Y_test_undersample = train_test_split(X_undersample,Y_undersample,test_size=0.3)

#parameters
learning_rate = 0.05
training_epoch = 10
batch_size = 43
display_step = 1

#tf graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,18])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])

#set model weights
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([18,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

#construct model
pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,w) + b) #softmax activation

#minimize error using cross entropy
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(pred),reduction_indices=1))
#Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

#initializing variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

#launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    #training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epoch):
        total_batch = len(X_train_undersample)/batch_size
        avg_cost = 0
        #loop over all the batches
        for batch in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs = X_train.iloc[(batch)*batch_size:(batch+1) *batch_size]
            batch_ys = Y_train.iloc[(batch)*batch_size:(batch+1) *batch_size]
            # run optimizer and cost operation
            _,c= sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict={x:batch_xs,y:batch_ys})
            avg_cost += c/total_batch


        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))

        #disply log per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            train_accuracy, newCost = sess.run([accuracy, cost], feed_dict={x: X_test,y: Y_test})
            print "test_set_accuracy:",accuracy.eval({x:X_test_undersample,y:Y_test_undersample})*100
            print "whole_set_accuracy:",accuracy.eval({x:X,y:Y})*100
            # print train_accuracy
            # print "cost",newCost
            print

    print 'optimization finished.'
```

Things I've tried to figure out what's causing it:

- Tried changing train dataset length.
- Dropped some not needed fields.
- Tried putting validation blocks.

Dataset :[link](https://www.kaggle.com/dalpozz/creditcardfraud)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I have edited your post to make it better readable (formatting) and remove things that don't belong in a post here. Please review the [tour] and after that click on the link "edited ... ago" above my avatar (or that of anyone else who last edited your post) to see the edit history, so you can see what was removed/changed (and hopefully learn from that). I have no knowledge of your subject matter, but a better post always increases the chances of someone answering.

Comment: Thanks @Anthon . Appreciate it.

Comment: your network seems to be quite small? A learning rate of 0.05 might be on the high side, have you tried plotting your training/validation loss to look at it's curve? Why do you have a batch size of 43?

Comment: We need you to give us appropriate details.  Show us the evidence of over-fitting, the history of training statistics (loss, accuracy, etc.).  Leaving us to desk-check your code is not the way to attract responses.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons of why it is overfitting , and as well there can be multiple ways to debug it and to fix it. Its hard to tell just from the code, because it also depends on the data, but here are some common reaons as well as fixes:

- Too small dataset, adding more data its a common overfitting fix
- Too complex model, if you have many features, or complex polonomial features, try to reducing complexity using feature selection
- Add regularization: i dont see regularization in your code, try to add it.